# apache caml converting xml to json

Tags: java, apache-camel

i am trying to convert xml to json using apache camel xmltojson , below are my two classes :

```
public class Route extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
    xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
    from("file:resource/inbox").marshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("file:resource/outbox");
    }

 }
```

And the main class

```
 public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Route routeBuilder = new Route();
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    try {
        context.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        context.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And below is the xml in src/main/resource/inbox folder

```
   <message>
   <splash name="hello" text="hello"/>
   <splash name="Kaise ho" text="Kaise ho"/>
   <tag name="Latest" text="Latest"/>
   <tag name="New" text="New"/>
   <tag name="Just Added" text="Just Added"/>
   <tag name="Featured" text="Featured"/>
   <tag name="Popular" text="Popular"/>
   <tag name="Just Arrived" text="Just Arrived"/>
   <tag name="New Arrival" text="New Arrival"/>
   <promptlogin name="hello" text="hello"/>
   <promptsubscribe name="hello" text="hello"/>
   </message>
```

it is giving the below error :

```
 org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XmlJsonDataFormat@49070868] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:resource/inbox]] -> [Marshal[org.ap... because of Data format 'xmljson' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the camel-xmljson dependency to your project?

If I remember correctly you need to add the XOM dependency explicitly (due to incompatible license):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xom</groupId>
  <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-xmljson</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>

Comment: Thanks working now .. but in json it is showing '@' symbol with each attribute , how to escape that ?

Comment: Maybe you need to look into the XmlJsonDataFormat option.